# Magento 2 Product checkout isnt load

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image]

And console show this error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler.js:34 [2017-12-13 03:21:35] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ /magento2/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler.js:34
/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/en_GB/Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Sm/himarket/en_GB/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler.js:34 [2017-12-13 03:21:35] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals" component.

Comment: Did you recently add any new plugins? Try to turn them off if you do. I've had the experience a few times that anything you add to your Magento might collide with the Checkout and break it.

Comment: I try but still problem is same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 checkout page not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205560/magento-2-checkout-page-not-loading)